# Checking which elements have a class and toggling them

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I am playing around with jsplumb, and I am using it to draw lines between div elements. My div elements serve as destination tags which are positioned on top of a background image. Ultimately, I am trying to form a flight routes map.

For example, when a user presses LONDON LUTON on the map - `<div id="luton">` it will toggle class `selected` on the element and show all destinations from LONDON LUTON, with lines connecting div elements. When the user presses `<button class="route-map reset">`, it will reset all the div elements within `route-map` element, disable jsPlumb connections, and toggle the selected class on the selected element.

How can I find elements which currently have the `selected` class assigned to them, and toggle them off?

```
$("#luton").on('click', function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $("#rotterdam").show();

$(".route-map.reset").on('click', function() {
    $('div.route-map').children().show();
    $('div.route-map > div').toggleClass('selected');
    jsPlumb.detachEveryConnection();
});
```

Comment: Could you at least show your HTML too? A jsfiddle would be best but not necessary

Comment: "How can I find elements which currently have the selected class assigned to them" Just use `$('.selected')`

Comment: Did you tried [jQuery.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would remove the class `selected` from all elements that have that class currently assigned to them.

```
$(".selected").removeClass("selected");
```